# android json parsing No value for tag

Tags: android, json, parsing

I need to parse JSON using following code

```
    urlGetDeviceIdMobileNo = Global.URL + "device_id="
                    + strDeviceIdLocal;

public class GetDeviceId extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginScreen.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urlGetDeviceIdMobileNo);
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!! json==="+json);

            try {

                strDeviceIdServer = (String) json.getString(TAG_DEVICE_ID);
                strMobileNoServer = (String) json.getString(TAG_MOBILE_NO);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
}
```

My Json data is :

```
{
   status: "success",
   data: 
   {
      device_id: "35xxxxxxcccccvvvv",
      mobile_number: "955896xxxxx"
   }
}
```

But logcat says:

```
  org.json.JSONException: No value for device_id
```

Comment: There's lacking, JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("data"); And then String deviceId = obj.getString("device_id");

Comment: After posting `device_id` to server are you also getting `device_id` from `JSON`?? and u missed ur "data" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace this

```
try {

                strDeviceIdServer = (String) json.getString(TAG_DEVICE_ID);
                strMobileNoServer = (String) json.getString(TAG_MOBILE_NO);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

WITH

```
try {

            strDeviceIdServer = json.getJSONObject("data").getString(TAG_DEVICE_ID);
            strMobileNoServer = json.getJSONObject("data").getString(TAG_MOBILE_NO);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your parsing is incorrect. Your JSONObject has child JSONObject "data", and this child JSONObject contains device_id. Therefore, you must parse it like:

```
try {
        JSONObject childJson = json.getJSONObject("data");
        if(childJson.has(TAG_DEVICE_ID))
            strDeviceIdServer = childJson.getString(TAG_DEVICE_ID);
        if(childJson.has(TAG_MOBILE_NO))
            strMobileNoServer = childJson.getString(TAG_MOBILE_NO);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```